# Cocos2D V3 Multiple Touch Sprite Movement

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having some trouble converting this game via the Raywenderlich site to work with cocos2d V3. I modified it to use touch so that wherever you touch on the screen the ship will move to that point on the x-axis. This worked fine with very similar code on V2 but causes the ship to behave very erratically in version 3. I have linked a video with the complete code as well as an example of what's happening for the most clear picture. Also, here is what I have in the touchbegan method.

Video with complete code and example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErzPGhHXKaE

```
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;

    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
    [_ship runAction:[CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(touchLocation.x, _ship.position.y)]];
    NSLog(@"touch");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable touch first:

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    CCLOG(@"on enter");
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
    [super onEnter];
}
```

Comment: It was shown in the video, but I've added touch interaction in the init method. The problem I am still stuck on is the ship going past the point selected with the CCActionMoveto function.